# Team A and B Randomizer without duplicates - Code works only for team A

Tags: excel, vba

```
Team 1 A,B,C
Team 2 D,E,F
```

My Script only pairs Team 1 (only pairing from 1 column). How do I incorporate Team 2 to be paired with team 1 with no duplicates the next time I'm pairing?

Only to have Team 1 be paired with Team 2. Team 1 doesn't need to be paired for they are already on a team.

```
Sub RandomPairing()

  Dim Cnt As Long, RandomIndex As Long, Tmp As Variant, Arr As Variant
  Randomize

  Arr = Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

  Arr = Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

  For Cnt = UBound(Arr) To 1 Step -1
    RandomIndex = Int((Cnt - LBound(Arr) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(Arr))
    Tmp = Arr(RandomIndex, 1)
    Arr(RandomIndex, 1) = Arr(Cnt, 1)
    Arr(Cnt, 1) = Tmp

  Next
  Range("G4").Resize(UBound(Arr)) = Arr
  Range("G4").Offset(UBound(Arr) / 2).Resize(UBound(Arr)).Cut Range("H4")

End Sub
```

The current output randomizes team 1

A, B

C, A

B, C

I would like the current output to Randomize team 1 with team 2

Output:

A, D

C, F

B, D

Without Duplicates.

Comment: "Only to have Team 1 be paired with Team 2. Team 1 doesn't need to be paired for they are already on a team." this seems to be a contradictory statement. It may be useful to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59972896/edit) to include sample data, and the expected result. Also an explanation of what the current output is and how it differs from  expectations would be useful

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Hopefully my edit provided a little more clarification.

Comment: No need to randomize both teams, list team 1 alphabetically, match each member with a randomly selected member of team 2 and voilà! Random pairing!